# Setup Port Forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, imac

Please help me setup a port forwarding.

iMac ➜ Raspberry Pi ➜ My PC using Termius

I know my RaspberryPi's public IP, but not my iMac's one.
The Raspberry Pi is in the same house as I'm in, and my iMac is at my 2nd house.

Comment: I think you mean setting up a SSH tunnel - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @journeyman-geek trying to use remotely my iMac that is at my parents home with SSH while im at my house.

Comment: Since yesterday you asked five questions about nearly the same thing. Please stop doing that and take a moment to decide what you're trying to do. Do you need an answer that involves the Raspberry Pi, or do you need an answer that involves your OVH webserver, or all of them, or none of them?

Comment: As you want, I just want to remotely use my iMac. Please answer, if you don't like my posts.

Comment: Unless the Pi is being used as a router, port forwarding [DNAT] would be configured on the router that's upstream of the end device [iMac]. Unless the ISP has assigned a _static_ IP to the modem providing internet to the iMac, a DDNS [Dynamic DNS] address would need to be configured on the iMac's router _(most ISPs don't provide static IPs and those that do usually charge a monthly fee for it that exceeds the cost of a DDNS subscription, such as [DynDNS](https://account.dyn.com/))_

Comment: This is a duplicate of at least 2 other questions OP has posted over the past 2 or so days. One of their other questions is closed as a duplicate of this: https://superuser.com/questions/1834600/how-to-setup-port-forwardng-to-connect-ssh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup port forwardng to connect (SSH)](https://superuser.com/questions/1834600/how-to-setup-port-forwardng-to-connect-ssh)